# Running firebase cloud function fails with a SyntaxError

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am following all the steps presented in this [link](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/writing-deploying-functions) but it does not seem to be sending me anywhere thus I am asking for help here. I have a sample function that I want to first test and then deploy to firebase cloud function but its failing with this message:

> > HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request x-powered-by: Express content-security-policy: default-src 'none' x-content-type-options:
> > nosniff content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 content-length: 1295
> > date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 13:05:48 GMT connection: close
>
> Error
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at
> position 0
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>
>    at createStrictSyntaxError
> (C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
>
>    at parse
> (C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>
>    at
> C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
>
>    at invokeCallback
> (C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>
>    at done
> (C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>
>    at IncomingMessage.onEnd
> (C:\Users\janic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>
>    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
>   
>  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
>
>    at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
> ```

I do not have any syntax error in the code, I literally copied the code from the link.

```
// functions/index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const faker = require('faker');

// Initialize products array
const products = [];

// Max number of products
const LIMIT = 100;

// Push a new product to the array
for (let i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
   products.push({
      name: faker.commerce.productName(),
      price: faker.commerce.price(),
   });
}

exports.listProducts = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   return products;
});
```

and I invoke it from the console using this command:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"data":{}}' http://localhost:5001/bleconnect/us-central1/listProducts
```

Edit:

The error indicates there is something wrong with the parsing, however, even after trying to return a simple string "Test", it still throws the same error.

Comment: When testing functions, I suggest to also try the tools for testing: `gcloud functions call`, or the testing tab in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data being returned has most likely already been parsed, is not JSON at all, or is an incorrectly stringified JSON string.

Comment: that's what the error message assumes but it doesn't necessarily mean that. I have tried to return only a string "Test" but it throws exactly the same error.

Comment: Yes, because just "Test" isn't correct JSON either. You'd have to return something along the lines of "{"test":true}".

Comment: @showtime does this answer helped you? if it helped you could you please upvote it or accept it to help the community? Thanks.